# enabling javascript in asp-classic

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp-classic

I can detect the status of a browser if it is disabled or not. Can I make the users browser's Javascript status changed. Which means if it is disabled , I want to make it enabled by server side code of classic-asp. Any other server-side language will do.But Is it possible?

Comment: I beg your pardon? Do you want to *enable* JavaScript support from the server if the browser does not support JavaScript or the user has decided to turn it off? How could you do such a thing?

Comment: You can't turn the browser JS engine on if its diabled. Would be a horrible security risk (where its been deemed a risk to have it enabled in the first place).

Comment: Well thanks guys thats what I though. Though I asked for it if it is really possible or not

Answer (score 2):

No it is not possible to enable JavaScript in the user's browser through server-side code of any kind. If your application relies on JavaScript, you can make use of the `<noscript>` tag to inform the user that they require JavaScript to be enabled.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/noscript.html